# Ozone as an energy source?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Would an engine that electrically generates ozone from the oxygen in air then uses it as fuel be efficient or possible? (This is not a Newtonian question – we’re talking chemical reaction not conservation of energy.)
Or what if ozone was used as an additive to the air intake for possible better fuel mileage on gas vehicles? (Those electric arc lighters produce ozone and are marketed as being wind proof so I wonder if an arc were safely maintained within the air intake if that would provide any boost?)

Ozone will combust in certain concentrations and even when in a solution of water if temperature is raised to the combustion temperature (which is quite low.)

As for the use of ozone as an energy source I believe the safest way to do so would be to make it on the fly and not store any amount that is not immediately used because it is a strong oxidizer and unstable.
Years ago I remember using a small van der graaf generator and recall that particular smell of ozone that is emitted while it runs. It doesn’t take long — maybe just a few seconds before I could smell the ozone in the air after turning on the machine. Also, with those electric arc lighters you can smell ozone being generated when you use.

So ultimately I’m asking: would it be possible to use a mix of ozone and air as the source of combustion inside an internal combustion engine? Or what about an ozone and water solution plus air for use as combustion source for combustion engines? What would be the byproduct of this?

Ozone as energy source for electric automobiles, jets, air planes etc?

## Disclaimer: If you’re reading this please do not try at home. Ozone is dangerous at certain concentrations.

Comment: You could potentially use Ozone as a combustion fuel, but not as an *energy source* - as you need to put energy in to generate the Ozone... The mechanical input into the van der graaf generator is the energy source, and you might as well use that input to drive the car...

Comment: A few things here.  Ozone will react with anything not passivated or inert. This ranges from certain types of metal and oil, grease or other lubricants.

Comment: Maybe start here: Effect of ozone on combustion of compression ignition engines  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0010218091901544

Comment: You can also get unwanted oxidation or combustion of lubricants so fluorinated grease would be required.